# Second header in odd number pages in IEEEtran class?

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran

How to get the second header in odd number pages in `IEEEtran` class..? Following the example code, I'm working around.

I should suppose to get "SKM: My IEEE article" on odd pages starting from 3, 5, 7,...

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cite,graphicx,amssymb,amsfonts,booktabs,multirow,array,comment}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage[all,graph]{xy}
\title{Affect of Motion Direction}
\author
{\IEEEauthorblockN{SKM}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Faculty of Electrical Engineering\\
University of XYZ\\
skm@mail.com}
}
\markboth{IEEE Transactions on \LaTeX}{SKM: My IEEE article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[1-10]
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE resource: [IEEEtran.cls](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls)

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `IEEEtran` article uses the `oneside` class option, meaning only the left header is used. To actually use `\markboth`, its as easy as calling `twoside` instead:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{IEEEtran}
```

#### Footnotes:

IMO, calling `\markboth` should default the class option to `twoside`, but I'm no class architect.

Source: reading the [IEEEtran.cls](http://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls) file code.